# Get sum of goals scored by each team

Tags: python, list

I am analyzing a football games dataset and I want to answer a question - how many goals each team has scored and lost.

My dataset:

```
date         home_team    away_team    home_score    away_score
1873-03-08   England      Scotland     0             1
1873-03-09   Scotland     England      1             0
...          ...          ...          ...           ...
```

The function takes in 2 parameters - start year and end year

I've tried to have an empty list at a start, while iterating through the whole set add the name of the country and append the goals they've scored but since there are many different teams my list is not correct.

```
def total_goals(start, end):
        x = 0
        goals_scored = 0
        goals_scored_list = []
        goals_lost = 0
        goals_lost_list = []
        complete_list = []

        for item in range(len(data['home_team'])):
            date = int(data['date'][x][:4])
            if date >= start:
                if date <= end:
                    if int(data['home_score'][x]) > int(data['away_score'][x]):
                        goals_scored_list.append(data['home_team'])
                        goals_scored_list.append(data['home_score'])
                        x += 1
                    else:
                        x += 1

        return goals_scored_list
```

My desired output would be a list which would contain a list for each unique team, that list would have country name, goals scored and goals lost:

```
[['England',1,1],['Scotland',0,2],[...]]
```

I assume I would need to create a list for each unique country, maybe using something like

```
if country not in data['home_team']:
    goals_scored_list.append(data['home_team'][x]
```

But I believe there is a more sophisticated way to achieve my goal.

Comment: what is the exact question? Maybe include a link to the dataset and the rest of the code.

Comment: The question is basically what kind of structure should I use. The perfect answer would be the code snippet. I use data from here - https://www.kaggle.com/martj42/international-football-results-from-1872-to-2017

Comment: it looks like you loop over ```len(data['home_team'])``` as ```item``` but don't use item anywhere

Comment: do you use pandas?  can you show the structure of data ?

Comment: Yes, the data structure is shown in my question as .csv file where headers are column names. I declare the file as data and call columns as data['home_score']

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```py
class Team:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.wins = 0
        self.losses = 0


    def addEl(self,pos,score):
        try:
            score = int(score)
        except Exception as e:
            print e
        if pos:
            self.wins += score
        else:
            self.loss += score



def total_goals(start,end):
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(data)):
        date = int(data['date'][i])

        if date >= start and date <= end: #make sure it's in the params
            pos = int(data['home_score'][i]) > int(data['away_score'][i]) #true if home wins, false otherwise

            if data['home_team'][i] in d: #check if home_team already exists
                d[data['home_team']].addEl(pos,data['home_score'][i]) #add score to wins/losses
            else:
                d[data['home_team'][i]] = Team(data['home_score'][i])
                d[data['home_team'][i]].addEl(pos,data['home_score'][i])


            if data['away_team'][i] in d:
                d[data['away_team']].addEl(not(pos),data['away_score'][i])
            else:
                d[data['away_team'][i]] = Team(data['away_score'][i])
                d[data['away_team'][i]].addEl(not(pos),data['away_score'][i])


    return d
```

Using a custom class has the advantage of letting you add more characteristics like how many games were won/lost, additional statistics etc.etc.

Comment: Hi, i've tried running the script and I get the following error - `unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'`, I think you've mistyped addE instead of addEl at the else part which I've adjusted to be addEl. Any idea why would I bump in to the error? And I assumed `def total_goals` are inside of class team, is that right?

Comment: try again, I've edited the code, I believe the problem was that you have to convert to int

Comment: Hm, I am still getting the same error. Also, in your `def total_goals` the function should take 2 parameters start and end, in your script you define `start_end`, I've converted it to `(start, end)`, unless this is syntax I am not aware of. The issue is pointing at `self.wins += score`

Comment: does it raise an exception?

Comment: No, it does not. It gives error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: "Ivory Coast"`. Looks like at some point you are trying to add int with str. `File "football.py", line 369, in addEl
    self.wins += score
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'`